# Re-Installing Application from Application Center Client gives Error

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-appcenter

Worklight 6.1.0.1

I am getting the below error if i Re-Install my application from Application Center Client.

[image]

Steps to Reproduce:

1. Install the Worklight Application from App Center Client.
2. After successful installation, Open the installed Worklight app. Works fine.
3. Press Home button. The Worklight application is still running in the background
4. Open IBM Application Center Client.
5. Navigate to the same application.
6. Press "Install" button. The device again start downloading and installing the same application.
7. After installation complete, open the application. It will immediately throws the above issue.

[Click here to get my Device Console - Log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/g6ec7crqcko17ob/iPhone-Console.log)

Comment: Does this happen with a simple HelloWorld application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This effect depends on the particular application. Some applications require to be uninstalled before they can be reinstalled. This happens in particular when the application uses local data, since this data is not cleared when you install the application over itself. In your case, I can see from the log that the Web Resources Integrity test failed. The log does not show why, but my guess is that it might be caused by data that the old installation left on the device.

Due to iOS limitations, the Application Center Client cannot automatically uninstall the application. There is no API for uninstall, unless you use an MDM solution. Hence, the Application Center Client simply installs the application over itself without uninstalling it before.

In order to be on the safe side, I recommend to uninstall the old application explicitly before you install it again.